# Remove Items from recursive list by property

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a data-structure like this

```
public class DomainObject
{
    public List<DomainObject> Children { get; private set; }
    public List<Car> Cars { get; private set; }
}

public class Car 
{
    public bool Sold { get; }
}
```

So my structure is quite nested and I want to remove all `Car` which aren't flagged as `Sold`.

Here an example of what I actually want

```
List
  DomainObject
    Children
      Car A (Sold)
      Car B (!Sold)
      Car C (Sold)
    Children
      Car D (!Sold)
      Car E (!Sold)
      Car F (Sold)
```

becomes

```
List
  DomainObject
    Children
      Car A
      Car C
    Children
      Car F
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive function should do it.

```
public void RemoveNonSoldCars(DomainObject parent)
{
    parent.Cars.RemoveAll(x => !x.Sold);
    foreach (var item in parent.Children)
        RemoveNonSoldCars(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that takes the `DomainObject` then removes all non-sold cars from their `Cars` variable. That could be done with a reverse `for` loop or using `RemoveAll` with `linq`. End the method by calling itself for all children objects in it.